# triggering reveal modal from link loaded in with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

I have this link:

```
<a data-reveal-id="about" href="#">Learn more</a>
```

This opens a modal with `id="about"` just fine.

If I load in some content to my page that has this same link, it does *not* open the same modal.

To me, this is a bug in Foundation 5's javascript. While I patiently wait for Zurb to fix it, is there a workaround available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to open your reveal modal

when user clicks call this one..

```
 $('#about').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```